# OMR: evaluate filled circle

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, omr

I'm implementing OMR system for test papers. But faced with problems when determining filled circles. I've succeeded in getting these grayscale regions of interest .

The problems are:
 - Binary thresholding (adaptive and fixed) and counting non zero pixels gives a lot of errors because of letters in a circles and different brightness of photos made by mobile cameras.
 - Also tried technique described in this [survey](http://www.academia.edu/30571353/Various_Techniques_for_Assessment_of_OMR_Sheets_through_Ordinary_2D_Scanner_A_Survey) that uses average grayscale values of a circle do mark it filled or not, but the brightness of an image is not uniform because of different light sources when people take photos be their cameras and I got a lot of wrong results.
- People also doesn't follow rules such us filling the whole circle, algorithm also need to be robust in such cases.
[Sample images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4inB.png)
I already have about 10 GBs of samples, so may be machine learning or other statistical methods will be useful.
Does anybody know other methods to classify a circle as filled?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad. there are many ways and many possible solutions but giving a good recommendation would require more images and some constraints. so far my answer would be: yes someone knows other methods to classify a circle as filled.

Comment: @vzhadeyev Check 'finding contours' using the property of area

Comment: @JeruLuke, this will give me the array of the contours with some area, from which I can get the largest one or check the number of filled pixel inside of it, but I will still have to put some fixed threshold on the number of pixels to say is it filled or not. Is that your point?

Comment: @vzhadeyev Yes exactly. It is a trial and error method to decide the area of the contour that you want to highlight

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not a straight forward problem, it needs lot of tweaking to make it robust. But I would like suggest you a good starting point. You can play with it and try to make it work.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image_ori = cv2.imread("circle_opt.png")

lower_bound = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper_bound = np.array([255, 255, 195])
image = image_ori

mask = cv2.inRange(image_ori, lower_bound, upper_bound)
masked_red = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

contours = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
contours.sort(key=lambda x:cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

print len(contours)
for c in contours:
    (x,y),r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    r = int(r)
    if 10 <= r <= 15:
        cv2.circle(image,center,r,(0,255,0),2)

# cv2.imwrite('omr_processed.png', image_ori)
cv2.imshow("original",image_ori)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result I got from my code on the image you shared was this

[image: Green circles]

You can apply thresholds to these green circled patches and then count non-zeros to get if the circle is marked or not. You can play with lower and upper_bound to try to make the solution robust.

Hope this helps! Good luck on your problem solving :)

Comment: Getting TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: this was tested on python 2.7, try with that. Or modify the code to work in the version you are using.

Comment: Yeah, using the same environment. Not sure why it gave that error when being passed into the sort function, so also not sure what to correct. 'Key' was not used before that.

Comment: You can just comment out that line. Sorting is not necessary if just want to check the functionality :)